# "Invalid Object Name" error during db.SaveChanges() (Entity Framework/MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, ef-database-first

(Solved)

I am getting a really strange error when trying to save changes to an entity from an app we are building.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ReportID,RecordID,ReportName,FileName,ReportTypeID,OwningApplicationID,RecordCID,AssignedUserID")] Report report)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(report).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.OwningApplicationID = new SelectList(db.Applications, "ApplicationID", "ApplicationName", report.OwningApplicationID);
        ViewBag.ReportTypeID = new SelectList(db.ReportTypes, "ReportTypeID", "ReportTypeText", report.ReportTypeID);
        return View(report);
    }
```

At db.SaveChanges() I get the following error:

`An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code`

If I examine the inner exceptions I find this:

`"Invalid object name 'tg_DataCleaningMaintenance_PendingInsert__20150709_000000_953cccd7-0ba4-4b3e-ae5d-df6b936841f8'."`

The exception occurs here:

`at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func'2 updateFunction)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func'1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()`

I cannot find anything online about DataCleaningMaintenance_PendingInsert or anything similar. I do remember seeing a table with a similar name in the database over a week ago, it has since been deleted.

I have updated my model from the database, rebuilt the project, scoured the project for any reference to this table, verified that the table does not exist in the database. I examine the db object during debugging and can't find any reference to this object, and I have verified that the connection string is correct and includes the database name (not just the server name). I have no idea how to approach this problem at this point. Please help!

Thanks!

EDIT: There was indeed a trigger set on the Report table in SQL Server, which was causing the server to reject my update with the above message. The trigger appears to have come from an SSIS package that used FuzzyLookup on this table. Deleting the trigger should fix this problem.

Comment: Have you checked the database for any triggers? Are you doing any kind of logging in your code anywhere... maybe a custom ObjectContext.SaveChanges method or something?

Comment: No custom logging, no triggers. I had the thought about triggers as well.

Comment: Try inserting a dummy item using SQL management studio itself to see if it gives a better error message. If the insert works, then you might want to check your EDMX Model Browser for anything with a similar name.

Comment: I was wrong! There is a trigger looking for that table in the Report table. I don't know how I missed it earlier. Can you post an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved thanks to user br4d!

There was a trigger on the Report table in SQL Server, left over from an SSIS package that used FuzzyLookup on this table. I'm unsure how I missed it as I definitely checked for triggers in SSMS. I used this query to find it:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) Obj,
  SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) [Schema],
  OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) Parent,
  type_desc Obj_Type
  FROM sys.objects
) Objects
WHERE Obj LIKE 'tg_%'
```

Saw that it was a trigger on Report, double checked the Triggers folder and lo and behold, there it was. It was looking for the tg_DataCleaning_xxx table on INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE queries. Deleted it and no longer had any problems.

There was no problem in my application code after all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to your model, then Ctrl+A to select all tables/views/etc, and then press delete.

Then update from database again.

I've had several random errors appear in EF because the 'update from database' doesn't remove old objects that have long since been deleted!!

Obviously probably worth doing a backup first, though i have never had a problem using this technique.